# How to get range of cells into a specific array dimension

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get a range of cells into an array, which by itself is simple enough:

```
Dim matchArray As Variant
matchArray = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("B2:B12000").Value2
```

This creates a two-dimensional array with one column as the second dimension and if you expand the range to include a second column it creates a two-dimensional array with two columns for the second dimension:

```
matchArray = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("B2:C12000").Value2
```

But what if the two columns aren't next to each other and you don't want the one in the middle?

```
matchArray = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("B2:B12000,D2:D12000").Value2
```

The above would be my best guess but it doesn't work, it only returns the first range specified.

So what I need is a way to return a range cell values into a specific dimension of the array.

I know I could do it by looping through the rows but that would take far too long with the number of rows I'm going to be working with.

Comment: "This creates a one dimensional array" -- but it doesn't. It creates a two dimensional array with only 1 column.

Comment: To expand on @JohnColeman's comment, you are creating a two dimension array with 1 to 11999 in the **first rank** and 1 to 1 in the **second rank**.

Comment: Have you tried a `Union`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need a loop -- but loop over VBA arrays rather than individual cells:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, C As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    B = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("B2:B12000").Value2
    C = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("D2:D12000").Value2
    ReDim A(1 To 11999, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To 11999
        A(i, 1) = B(i, 1)
        A(i, 2) = C(i, 2)
    Next i
    'do stuff with A
End Sub
```

This should only take a fraction of a second.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you yesterday, had to work quickly to try to get this implemented before the day was over. With some refactoring this worked for my code nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a ragged array:

```
Dim var1(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim var As Variant
var = Range("A1:A10").Value2
var1(1) = var
var = Range("c1:c10").Value2
var1(2) = var
MsgBox var1(1)(3, 1)
```

Comment: Isn't it called a "jagged" array? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more ways:

```
Sub Example1()
    Const lookupSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim matchArray As Variant, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

    With Sheets(lookupSheet)
        arr1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("B2:B12000").Value2)
        arr2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("D2:D12000").Value2)
        matchArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(arr1, arr2))
    End With
End Sub

Sub Example2()
    Const lookupSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim matchArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    With Sheets(lookupSheet)
        matchArray = .Range("B2:B12000").Resize(, 2).Value2
        For Each v In .Range("D2:D12000").Value2
            x = x + 1
            matchArray(x, 2) = v
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably no quicker than John Coleman's answer, but I think this does what you want.

```
Sub x()

Dim matchArray, r As Range

Set r = Sheets(lookupSheet).Range("B2:D12000")

matchArray = Application.Index(r, Evaluate("Row(1:" & r.Rows.Count & ")"), Array(1, 3))

End Sub
```